# URL Rewrite - change URL text between slashes

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I have URLs like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/carmake/ABCDEFG/123456789
http://www.mywebsite.com/carmake/AAABBBC/124532532
http://www.mywebsite.com/carmake/BNDFKNV/463634213
```

and I want to change them to this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/carmake/parts/123456789
http://www.mywebsite.com/carmake/parts/124532532
http://www.mywebsite.com/carmake/parts/463634213
```

How can I change the text between the last to slashes to parts in `functions.php`

Comment: does the letters between last slashes are always CAPITAL letters ? EDIt : NVM have a better idea.

Comment: No. There are various text with letters, capital letters, numbers, hypens, etc.

Comment: What is the problem here? Is it really simply a replacement of those letters? If so, then this has been answered about 56483937575 times alone here on SO. All those answers did not help you? Why not?

Comment: What .htaccess code you tried so far? please provide it.

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/sH1wA1/1

```
<?php

$string      = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/carmake/ABCDEFG/123456789';
$pattern     = '/(.*\/).*\/([^\/]*$)/';
$replacement = '${1}parts/${2}';

    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/carmake/ABCDEFG/123456789";
$parts = parse_url($url);
$path = $parts['path'];
$pos = strpos($path, '/', 9);
$sub = substr($path, 9, $pos - 9);
$url = str_replace($sub, 'parts', $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split to segments, change and collect back

```
$a = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/carmake/BNDFKNV/463634213';
$to = 'parts';
$s = explode('/', $a);
$s[count($s)-2] = $to;
echo implode('/', $s);
```